# Java: gradle build failed bootRepackage (on create jar)

Tags: java, spring, jar, build, gradle

Doing a web project means: Java (jdk 1.7.0.51) + Spring framework (+velocity) + Hibernate + Gradle + Apache Tomcat.
Suddenly, there was a problem: you can not make a build. To build using Gradle.

> 16:50:30: Executing external task 'build'...
>   :compileJava
>   :processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :classes
>   :jar
>   :bootRepackage FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.
>   MALFORMED
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 14.935 secs
>   MALFORMED

What could be the problem?

The full log:

> :bootRepackage FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.
>   MALFORMED
>   * Try:
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   * Exception is:
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.
>          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
>   java:69)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46
>   )
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskEx
>   ecuter.java:35)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExec
>   uter.java:42)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.j
>   ava:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.j
>   ava:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:286)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecut
>   or.java:79)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecut
>   or.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:
>   51)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>           at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
>           at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
>           at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStor
>   e.java:135)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(Defaul
>   tTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:93)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
>           at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter
>   .java:64)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:20
>   1)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:17
>   4)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.getClassEntries(MainClassFinder.java:237)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.doWithMainClasses(MainClassFinder.java:200)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.findSingleMainClass(MainClassFinder.java:187)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.findMainMethod(Repackager.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackageTask$LoggingRepackager.findMainMethod(RepackageTask.java:2
>   19)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.buildManifest(Repackager.java:206)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:139)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:122)
>           at org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackageTask$RepackageAction.repackage(RepackageTask.java:173)
>           at org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackageTask$RepackageAction.execute(RepackageTask.java:138)
>           at org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackageTask$RepackageAction.execute(RepackageTask.java:1)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$FilteredAction.execute(Actions.java:203)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:110)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.withType(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:120)
>           at org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackageTask.repackage(RepackageTask.java:89)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(Anno
>   tationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(Annota
>   tionProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(Annota
>   tionProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:530)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:513)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.j
>   ava:80)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
>   java:61)
>           ... 52 more
>   BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 13.0 secs

Answer (score 15):

If you don't use boot repackage you can simply disable `bootRepackage` tasks by adding this line into your build.gradle file:

```
bootRepackage.enabled = false
```

Otherwise you need to specify the main class:

```
bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'youPackage.Application'
}
```

You can find more instructions in [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)

Share your build.gradle if you still have problem.

Comment: This helped me solve building a JAR without packaging source classes under `BOOT-INF`:  BOOT-INF is what you want for a _runnable_ JAR, but NOT what you want for a _source/dependency_ JAR.

Answer (score 5):

From [Spring Boot release 2.0 M1](https://spring.io/blog/2017/04/05/spring-boot-s-new-gradle-plugin#building-executable-jars-and-wars) the `bootRepackage` task has been replaced with `bootJar` and `bootWar` tasks.