# Error while performing push command in git

Tags: java, heroku

Using the guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RHYDNSRSOs I want to deploy the application to Heroku. However, `git push heroku master` throws an error:

```
    :compileJava NO-SOURCE
       :processResources NO-SOURCE
       :classes UP-TO-DATE
       :findMainClass
       :jar
       :bootRepackage FAILED

       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

       * What went wrong:
       Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.
       > Unable to find main class

       * Try:
       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

       BUILD FAILED

       Total time: 15.555 secs
 !     ERROR: Failed to run Gradle!
       We're sorry this build is failing. If you can't find the issue in application
       code, please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com
       You can also try reverting to the previous version of the buildpack by running:
       $ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle#previous-version

       Thanks,
       Heroku
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Gradle app.
 !     Push failed
```

The project normally works during compilation in IntelliJ. They work without a problem.

Comment: So, what happens when you run it with --stacktrace, as suggested by the failure output?

Comment: This is not about git, it's about not building gradle application at Heroku. Please, edit the question.

Comment: I do not know git and I do not know how to use it --stacktrace ?

Comment: You should run something like `gradle build --stacktrace` on your machine.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/G830wVD1

Comment: Duplicate of? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528114/unable-to-find-main-class-bootrepackage

Comment: I still have some mistakes https://zapodaj.net/7066f1fe2cd5a.png.html

Comment: maybe it will be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708596/java-gradle-build-failed-bootrepackage-on-create-jar) for you